# How to combine the Artifact generated by several builds in Teamcity

Tags: java, teamcity

Here is the scenario.
There will be multiple builds running at the same time, each build will generate an Artifact, the Artifact itself is a test report.

I want to merge the multiple Artifact(test report) into one after all builds are finished.

I'm writing a new type build runner plugin, both for agent part and server part.
I think I should write a specific server plugin for this issue but I don't know is there any API for me to reach the goal?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think the best place to ask this is at the TeamCity [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW). You can raise it as a question rather than a bug.

Comment: Do you really need a plugin? You can create a "Master" configuration that will depend on all builds that generate reports (Artifact & Snapshot dependencies) and join them together.

Comment: @AlexanderDoroshenko Thanks. For the rule about "join" them together, I need to write the plugin I think.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thanks for you reminder. I will try that way if no response on SO.